# indexing zarr with both coordinate arrays and slice

Tags: python, zarr

Currently zarr support advanced indexing by coordinate arrays:

```
z = zarr.array(np.arange(3*4).reshape(3,4))
z.vindex[[0, 2], [1, 3]]
array([ 1, 11])
```

But the coordinate arrays have to be provided for each dimension.
If one dimension is indexing with slice, e.g.:

```
z = zarr.array(np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3, 4, 5))
z.vindex[[0, 2], [1, 3]] #None in the last dim
```

It will raise error.

I want to get an array of shape (2,5). Any kind of workaround?

I have tried

```
z.vindex[[0,2],[1,3],slice(None)]
```

But it doesn't work.